# RASA NLU: Multiple entity extraction from Single intent

Tags: python, tensorflow, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

Am trying to retrieve different entities from a single intent using rasa nlu below is the nlu part of training data

```
##intent communicate
 - communication address of [JhonDoe](name)
 - communication address of [Engineer](designation)
```

When I try this approach, I correctly get intent as communicate but even a spelling mistake of the entity value(like engineer) will result in entity list as empty. So for the above scenario how to tackle the problem to detect the different entity from same intent for same question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create more variation and probably a lookup table will be helpful. Try add in a different lookup files for both `name` and `designation` entity

Hope this helps!

Comment: I already tried that and it has been fruitful, Thanks for your help @wywy_ds0203

Comment: try with the DietClassifier. It should pick up better. Which entity extractor are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea! parse it through a spell check first. Or train a model that works on character embeddings similarity. But these are a few drawbacks we will always have to face.