# Rasa multiple lookups in same intent

Tags: nlp, rasa-nlu, rasa

I have been trying out Rasa NLU for a hotel booking chatbot. I am trying to extract two features, room type and number of rooms. 
Here is my nlu.md file

```
## intent:greet
- hey
- hello
- hi
- good morning
- good evening
- hey there

## intent:goodbye
- bye
- goodbye
- see you around
- see you later

## intent:affirm
- yes
- indeed
- of course
- that sounds good
- correct

## intent:deny
- no
- never
- I don't think so
- don't like that
- no way
- not really

## intent: book_room
- i would like to book a room
- i want a room
- i want to book room
- i would like a room
- i want to have a room
- i want to book
- i would like to book


## intent: book_n_rooms
-  [num_rooms] rooms
-  I would like to book [num_rooms]
-  I want [num_rooms] rooms
-  I need [num_rooms] rooms
-  I want to have [num_rooms] rooms

## intent: room_type
-  I would like a [room_type_name] room
-  Well, I want [room_type_name]
-  I need [room_type_name] rooms
-  I prefer [room_type_name] rooms

## book_room_all_details
-  I would like a [room_type_name] [num_rooms]
-  I would like [num_rooms] of [room_type_name]
-  I want [num_rooms] of [room_type_name]
-  I prefer [room_type_name] [num_rooms]
-  I like [num_rooms] of [room_type_name]
-  book [num_rooms] [room_type_name] rooms
-  I would like to book [num_rooms] [room_type_name]
-  I would like to book [2](num_rooms) [deluxe](room_type_name) rooms
-  I would like to book [3](num_rooms) [deluxe](room_type_name) type rooms
-  I want [1](num_rooms) [simple](room_type_name) room
-  I want [1](num_rooms) [simple](room_type_name) type room
-  I want [2](num_rooms) [simple](room_type_name) rooms
-  book [3](num_rooms) [simple](room_type_name) type rooms
-  book [3](num_rooms) [simple](room_type_name) rooms
-  I would like [5](num_rooms) rooms [deluxe](room_type_name) 
-  I want [5](num_rooms) rooms [deluxe](room_type_name) 
-  I prefer [5](num_rooms) rooms [deluxe](room_type_name) 
-  I prefer [5](num_rooms) rooms [deluxe](room_type_name) 
## regex:num_rooms
- [0-9]+

## lookup:room_type_name
- Simple
- Deluxe
- simple
- deluxe
- SIMPLE
- DELUXE

## intent:bot_challenge
- are you a bot?
- are you a human?
- am I talking to a bot?
- am I talking to a human?
```

When I give the input "book 2 deluxe rooms"
The bot asks me how many rooms are needed.
The intent is wrongly classified.
I tried this answer [RASA NLU: Multiple entity extraction from Single intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59550980/rasa-nlu-multiple-entity-extraction-from-single-intent), but this has not been fruitful.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `regex` and `lookup` are converted into features. Just because you list "DELUX" in your lookup table does not mean that your assistant is always extracting it as `room_type`. See also the [documentation](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/nlu/training-data-format/#lookup-tables) of Rasa.

I guess that your assistant is mainly not working, because your NLU data needs to be updated: 
(1) You need to replace `[num_rooms]` and `[room_type_name]` with proper values. Rasa will not replace `[num_rooms]` with a number by itself. The examples listed under the intents should be normal sentences.
(2) `book_room_all_details` should be marked as an intent, otherwise your assistant is not aware of that intent.

Here the updated NLU data:

```
## intent:book_room
- i would like to book a room
- i want a room
- i want to book room
- i would like a room
- i want to have a room
- i want to book
- i would like to book


## intent:book_n_rooms
-  [4](num_rooms) rooms
-  I would like to book [1](num_rooms)
-  I want [2](num_rooms) rooms
-  I need [3](num_rooms) rooms
-  I want to have [2](num_rooms) rooms

## intent:room_type
-  I would like a [deluxe](room_type_name) room
-  Well, I want [simple](room_type_name)
-  I need [Simple](room_type_name) rooms
-  I prefer [DELUXE](room_type_name) rooms

## intent:book_room_all_details
-  I would like to book [2](num_rooms) [deluxe](room_type_name) rooms
-  I would like to book [3](num_rooms) [deluxe](room_type_name) type rooms
-  I want [1](num_rooms) [Simple](room_type_name) room
-  I want [1](num_rooms) [simple](room_type_name) type room
-  I want [2](num_rooms) [SIMPLE](room_type_name) rooms
-  book [3](num_rooms) [simple](room_type_name) type rooms
-  book [3](num_rooms) [SIMPLE](room_type_name) rooms
-  I would like [5](num_rooms) rooms [deluxe](room_type_name) 
-  I want [5](num_rooms) rooms [DELUXE](room_type_name) 
-  I prefer [5](num_rooms) rooms [Deluxe](room_type_name) 
-  I prefer [5](num_rooms) rooms [deluxe](room_type_name) 

## regex:num_rooms
- [0-9]+

## lookup:room_type_name
 - Simple
 - Deluxe
 - simple
 - deluxe
 - SIMPLE
 - DELUXE
```